# Count the column value for certain time period

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I had a Dataframe like below, and would like to count number of 'Case' with 'Open' Status based on the current month + previous months(e.g. one year).

```
Current Month       Case      Status 
2019-06-01           1        Open 
2019-05-01           1        Open 
2019-04-01           1        Open 
2019-03-01           1        Closed
```

The expected output would like, thanks.

```
Current Month       Case      Status    Count
2019-06-01           1        Open        3    # (June + May + Apr)
2019-05-01           1        Open        2    # (May + Apr)
2019-04-01           1        Open        1    # (Apr)
2019-03-01           1        Closed      0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way

```
df=df.sort_values('CurrentMonth')
df['Count']=df['Status'].eq('Open').iloc[::-1].groupby([df.CurrentMonth.dt.year,df.Case]).cumsum()
df
Out[483]: 
  CurrentMonth  Case  Status  Count
0   2019-06-01     1    Open    3.0
1   2019-05-01     1    Open    2.0
2   2019-04-01     1    Open    1.0
3   2019-03-01     1  Closed    0.0
```

Comment: Great solution +1. I have a question. `df['Status'].eq('Open').iloc[::-1]` returns a bool Series, then how come a `.groupby` works on a series with no `CurrentMonth` and `Case` column?

Comment: @harvpan he's passing the Series themselves, not the keys, as the grouper, so it doesn't matter that the series doesn't have those columns.  You would only run into issues with different shapes.

Comment: Thanks, how about there is a date of last year but within one year period starting from CurrentMonth? e.g. 2018-12-01

Comment: @user3483203. Damn, I missed it. Thanks. It is a humble reminder that I need some coffee. :)

Comment: @harvpan you should already got it with  user3483203 help, This is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html, only need the shape same and index match :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen yeah. Got it. Thank you. You guys are awesome!

Comment: @JennyJingYu you need using pd.Grouper with freq Year